# How do I turn the system sound on for an alarm, or turn off the system mute. (Android)

Tags: java, android

I am building an application that requires an alarm, and if the user has muted their device or set it to DND, I want to know how to override it.

I am really struggling with clear details on how the permissions on the sound and notification system work, where they overlap etc.  I would like to have the user enable the right to have their DND preferences overridden.

To be clear.  Is there an call I can make to override the sound or notification settings set buy the user at the device level and if there is, what permissions if any do I need?

I am sorry if this is too general and understand if it is delisted.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private void playSound(Context context, int soundResId, int volFactor) {
    if (context != null) {
        try {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(soundResId);
            if (assetFileDescriptor != null) {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
                assetFileDescriptor.close();
            }
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        try {
                            mediaPlayer.reset();
                            mediaPlayer.release();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            mp = null;
                        }
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        try {
                            mediaPlayer.reset();
                            mediaPlayer.release();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            mp = null;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)/volFactor, 0);
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```